# jquery - Facebook tagging

Tags: jquery, facebook, plugins, autocomplete, tags

Is there a plugin that has similar behavoir like the Facebook tagging?

Whats so special about this, is that it features:

- Autocomplete in between typed words
- Special outputted html (which is synced with another input field)

[image: Tagging example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use jquery mention inputs [plugin](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/) its similar to facebook mentions

or you can use jquery sew [plugin](https://github.com/tactivos/jquery-sew)

Comment: jQuery mentions seems like the perfect solution to me! Perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery UI [widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/): which allows you to create a list of special words which will suggest + autocomplete te word when the user starts typing it.

You can handle the special formatted html by using the callback when a special word is chosen:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
select: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

**Added:** 
It's also possible to trigger it in the middle of a sentence, I did found an example on JSfiddle which allows you to do this.

Press the **@** anywhere in the sentence and type the first letter. You can change the select callback if you want some custom html arround it.

http://jsfiddle.net/UdUrk/

Hope this brings you closer to the solution.

Kevin

Comment: I've actually been messing around with that A LOT. But I've run into the problem where it seems impossible to have autocomplete in the middle of a sentence..., also, when I have the element (I've chosen a `span` with `contenteditable="true"`) its hard to see the difference between the tags (surrounded in `<b>` tags) and regular text (as the autocomplete get flattened text, not html code...)

Comment: Ah okay, i did add something to my answer. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Its better, but still not perfect. I think the jQuery mentions plugin is the best way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you were able to find a solution that seems to fit your needs, OP. For anyone else who happens to stumble upon this (and OP if my assumption was wrong) who is looking for a robust, actively-maintained solution...

...check out [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator): it is a jQuery plug-in which enables clients to create highlighted references to ("mentions") to predefined entities in text areas. It is mantained by this guy right here :) .